# Manipulação de arquivos C (pular linhas)

Tags: c, c++, random

Olá, Estou com um problema para pular linhas em um arquivo, eu utilizo o fgets(), mas ele sempre imprime a primeira linha do meu arquivo.

Eu também fiz alguns testes, e por algum motivo, ocorre apenas uma iteração e o x entra no if com o valor do random.

Obs: cada linha do arquivo é sempre < 30 caracteres.

```
void randInventario() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random = rand() % 10;
    nome = new char;
    desc = new char;

    strcpy(parm,"armas.txt");

    FILE* arquivo = fopen(parm,"rt");
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        cout << "Não foi possível abrir o arquivo." << "\n" << endl;
    }

    int x = 0;
    char text[30];
    while(!feof(arquivo))
    {
      if(x = random)
      {
       fscanf(arquivo, "%s %d %s\n", nome, &dano, desc);
       break;
      }
      fgets(text,30,arquivo);
      ++x;
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
  }
```

Comment: Já que está usando C++, não use `fgets`, `fscanf`, `fopen`, etc. Usando *streams* já pode ser um grande passo para facilitar o trabalho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int random = rand() % 10;
```

`random` vai ser `0`, ou `1`, ou ... `9`

```
  if(x = random)
  {
   fscanf(arquivo, "%s %d %s\n", nome, &dano, desc);
   break;
  }
```

Este `if` executa sempre que `random` seja  diferente de `0`. Alem disso atribui o valor de `random` a `x`.

**Sugestao: liga os *warnings* do teu compilador e toma atencao ao que eles dizem.**

substitui a condicao do `if` por uma comparacao (em vez duma atribuicao)

```
if (x == random) ...
```

Comment: Nossa, pura desatenção. Acabei desligando os warnings por outros motivos e acabei com um problema maior ainda. Obrigado!